# Intervalos de confianza de un modelo lineal mixto (lme) en R

Tags: r

De un modelo lineal mixto (lme), me interesa obtener los intervalos de confianza (IC) de todos los niveles de los factores fijos. Con la función `intervals()` consigo el intervalo del intercepto, como referente, y sólo de algunos niveles, pero no todos ¿Saben cómo puedo obtener los IC de todos los niveles?

El modelo es el siguiente:

```
Ca <- lme(fixed = Ca ~ ano+manejo, data = mc1, random = ~ 1 | parcela/subparcela, control=list(maxIter=1000, niterEM=1000))

intervals(Ca, which = "fixed")
Approximate 95% confidence intervals

 Fixed effects:
                lower      est.     upper
(Intercept)  6113.837  6960.000 7806.1632
anosiete    -2067.245 -1503.333 -939.4221
manejoO     -2112.795 -1154.167 -195.5381
```

faltarían los parámetros de otro año y tipo de manejo

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta no deja claro el paquete que está utilizando:

Bajo lme4 la regresión multinivel sería así:

```
Ca <- lme4::lmer(Ca ~ 1 + ano + manejo + (1 | parcela/subparcela)
```

lme4::fixef(Ca) muestra los efectos fijos de las variables de todos los niveles.
confint(Ca) proporciona los intervalos de confianza correspondientes.

```
confint(Ca)
```